# Wordpress custom post type array query multiple categories

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I am trying to query my custom post type "portfolio" and get it to return the post in selected categories, at the moment I can only get it to return one category, I want it to return post in 'graphic' 'interior' etc should I be querying the cat ids instead? Below is my code any help would be much appreciated thanks.

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'portfolio',
  'tax_query' => array(
   array(
   'taxonomy' => 'portfolio-category',
   'field' => 'slug',
   'terms' => 'graphic',
   'terms' => 'interior',
   )
  )
);

$portfolio_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:--

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'portfolio-category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'graphic', 'interior' )
        )
    )
);
```

Hope this will help you...